# Non-linearity of 'no current' boundary condition

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter

I am wondering about the possible definition of boundary condition between a metal and an insulator. The ideology I had in mind is 'No perpendicular current'.

The current usually is treated as $$J(x)=-i(\psi^*(x)\nabla\psi -\psi(x)\nabla\psi^*) \, .$$

But setting $J(x=0)=0$ seems to be a non linear boundary condition with either $\psi=0$ or $\nabla \psi=0 $ or even $\psi^*\nabla \psi\in \mathbb{R}$  so linear combination of two solutions will not be a solution.

The question is:
How can I state such a boundary condition without ignoring part of my space of solutions?

Comment: I thought about using the Local Current operator and not it's expectation value
 $\vec{J}(x_0)=\delta(x-x_0) \vec P+\vec P\delta(x-x_0)$
But I couldn't really see How...